# Highcharts multiple panes, with plotOptions Compare Percent in only one pane

Tags: highcharts

I have two panes (yAxis:0 and yAxis:1) for two different sets of data series. When I use plotOptions Compare set to Percent, the second pane (yAxis:1) becomes blank (or actually I think the curve is pushed to the very top, but still not visible). If I remove the plotOptions section, then the second pane comes out just like I want it. But then I don't get the first pane the way I want it (normalized so I can see the percentage difference rather than absolute value).
Is there a way to apply the plotOptions only to the first pane / yAxis:0?

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo : 'container'
    },

    title: {
        text : 'Relative rates for <?=$stock1?>, <?=$stock2?>, and OMX30, and positions taken'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 3,
            text: '3m'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 6,
            text: '6m'
        }, {
            type: 'ytd',
            text: 'YTD'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 4,
            text: '4y'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 5
    },

    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Normalized rates'
        },
        height: 250,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
            }
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 2,
            color: 'silver'
        }]
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Positions taken'
        },
        top: 300,
        height: 100,
        offset: 0,
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 2,
            color: 'silver'
        }]
    }],

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minRange: 1728000000   //Minimibredden på grafen i ms
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            compare: 'percent'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name : '<?=$stock1?>',
        data : json_data,
        yAxis : 0,
        tooltip: {
            yDecimals: 2
        }
    },{
        name : '<?=$stock2?>',
        data : json_data2,
        yAxis : 0,
        tooltip: {
            yDecimals: 2
        }
    },{
        name : 'OMX30',
        data : json_data3,
        yAxis : 0,
        tooltip: {
            yDecimals: 2
        }
    },{
        name : '<?=$stock1?>',
        data : json_data4,
        yAxis : 1,
        tooltip: {
            yDecimals: 1
        }
    },{
        name : '<?=$stock2?>',
        data : json_data5,
        yAxis : 1,
        tooltip: {
            yDecimals: 1
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: You can try to set options in series object, but could you supply a example with data ?